# Using a/an with several singular nouns

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Can I say:

**There is a shop, market and pharmasy.**

**I have a car, house and swimming pool.**

I mean, could I sometimes not duplicate articles a/an. If yes, then when?

Comment: As a learner: If you for example want to refer to a specific thing or something like: I have a car, **this** beautiful girl, and a beautiful apple in my hands! 0:-)